# Swift - find object in array of enums with associated values

Tags: arrays, swift, search, enums, associated-value

I have this enum:

```
enum Animal {       
    case cat(CatModel)
    case dog(DogModel)
}
```

And an array of animals:

```
var animals: [Animal]
```

I need to find a Cat object in this array by a property that Dog doesn't have. `litterBoxId` for example.

```
let cat = animals.first(where: {$0.litterBoxId == 7})
```

This of course has an error:

```
Value of type 'MyViewController.Animal' has no member 'litterBoxId'
```

How can I accomplish this? I also tried

```
($0 as CatModel).litterBoxId
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use pattern matching to accomplish this with 2 ways.

Using switch:

```
let cat = animals.first(where: {
    switch $0 {
    case .cat(let catModel) where catModel.litterBoxId == 7:
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
})
```

or if:

```
let cat = animals.first(where: {
    if case .cat(let catModel) = $0, catModel.litterBoxId == 7 {
        return true
    }
    return false
})
```

**Update**: As @Alexander-ReinstateMonica mentioned in his commnet, it would be more appropriate to hide this logic behind a function like this:

```
extension Animal {
    func matches(litterboxID: Int) -> Bool {
        switch self {
        case .cat(let catModel) where catModel.litterBoxId == 7:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

and then your code will be much cleaner:

```
let cat = animals.first(where: { $0.matches(litterboxID: 7) })
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this, it's a total mess that obscures intent. I would suggest to *at leasst* extract these into functions on the enum.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica so, a function in the enum that would take the array of enums and the `litterBoxId` as parameters? Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: At the most superficial level, you could introduce `func litterboxID(of: Animal, matches: Int) -> Bool`, and put your pattern matching logic in there, so you can just call `animals.first(where: { litterboxID(of: Animal, matches: 7) }`. Better yet, you should put access to those fields in the enum itself, as I mention in my answer (and the comments to it). Better better yet, use a protocol that can contain these fields (if applicable) and allows you easily to cast to get the rest

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica thank you. I update my answer with one of your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't a good use of enums, but here is how it *could* work:

```
struct CatModel {
    let litterBoxID: Int
}

struct DogModel {
    let litterBoxID: Int
}

enum Animal {       
    case cat(CatModel)
    case dog(DogModel)
    
    var litterBoxId: Int {
        switch self {
        case .cat(let cat): return cat.litterBoxID
        case .dog(let dog): return dog.litterBoxID
        }
    }
}

var animals: [Animal] = []
let cat = animals.first(where: { $0.litterBoxId == 7 })
```

You would be much better off using a protocol:

```
struct CatModel: Animal {
    let litterBoxID: Int
}

struct DogModel: Animal {
    let litterBoxID: Int
}

protocol Animal {
    var litterBoxID: Int { get }
}

var animals: [Animal] = []
let cat = animals.first(where: { $0.litterBoxID == 7 })
```

Comment: Part of the specification though was that DogModel doesn't have litterBoxID.

Comment: @soleil Then you can make the `litterBoxId` field optional, and write `{ $0.litterBoxID? == 7 }`. Alternatively, you can make  `var catModel: Cat?` and `var dogModel: Dog?`, and write `{ $0.cat?.litterBoxID == 7 }`. In either case, the much more natural approach is to use a protocol (to contain whatever properties happen to be in common), and cast for the parts that are specific: `{ ($0 as? Cat)?.litterBoxID == 7 }`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extension that gives you back an array of `CatModel`

```
extension Array where Element == Animal {
var cats: [CatModel] {
    var filteredCats = [CatModel]()
    self.forEach { animal in
        switch animal {
        case .cat(let catModel): filteredCats.append(catModel)
        case .dog: break
        }
    }
    return filteredCats
}
```

}

```
let cat = animals.cats.first(where: {$0.litterBoxId == 7})
```